# Populating combobox with XML attribute?

Tags: c#, xml, combobox

How should I populate combobox with XML attribute. My XML file is:

```
<dataSources>
    <dataSource id="1" name="support" dbtype="Oracle" dataSource="foo" initialCatalog="" userId="bar" password="x" />
</dataSources>
<services>
```

I need to populate 2 comboboxes with XML attribute names. I have the below code also but right now I am not getting the required output?

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("abc.xml");
XmlNodeList colorList = doc.SelectNodes("config/dataSources");
foreach (XmlNode dataSources in colorList)
{
    comboBox1.Items.Add(dataSources.InnerXml);
}

foreach (XmlNode dataSources in colorList)
{
    comboBox2.Items.Add(dataSources.InnerXml);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want value of attribute name:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("abc.xml");
XmlNodeList colorList = doc.SelectNodes("config/dataSources/dataSource");
foreach (XmlNode dataSources in colorList)
{
    comboBox1.Items.Add(dataSources.Attributes["name"].Value.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach (XmlNode dataSources in colorList)
{
    foreach(XmlAttribute attribute in dataSources.Attributes)
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Add(attribute.Name); // add the attribute name to cb1
        comboBox2.Items.Add(attribute.Value); // add the attribute value to cb2
    }
}
```